# How to merge first two lines of a csv column-by-column?

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have an excel file that I converted to csv. When converted, it looks like the following example (Please note that there are 100+ columns in the csv. This is a minified version):

```
,Product,"  ",Citty,"   ",Price
,Name," ",Location,"    ",Per Unit
,banana,"   ",CA,"  ",5.7
,apple,"    ",FL,"  ",2.3
```

I need to write a script that will take the first & second line and "merge" them together based on their comma position:

```
,Product Name," ""  ",Citty Location,"  ""  ",Price Per Unit
,banana,"   ",CA,"  ",5.7
,apple,"    ",FL,"  ",2.3
```

I've looked at other questions on here and stack overflow, but the answers don't seem to pertain to this weird column-by-column situation for just the first 2 lines of the file.

---

As an additional unrelated task, I'd also like to get rid of the empty columns in the csv and fix the spelling error so that it looks like this:

```
Product Name,City Location,Price Per Unit
banana,CA,5.7
apple,FL,2.3
```

(The csv currently has a tab surrounded by quotes between every actual column of data except for the first column, which is just empty followed by a comma).

I will be receiving the csv with the spelling error multiple times, so I would like to programmatically fix the error in the script. Please also note that the columns may not always be in the order shown above, so I need to dynamically check each column name for the error during the script.

Comment: CSV repair is fine, but you *might* consider getting the XLS source fixed also/instead.  Just saying.

Comment: @Wildcard Haha quite true, but another business group gives me the file so "spelling errors" become a low-priority fix on their end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$ awk -F, 'NR<2{split(gensub(/Citty/,"City","g",$0),a,FS)}NR==2{for(b=2;b<=NF;b+=2){c=c a[b]" "$b","}print gensub(/,$/,"",1,c)}NR>2{print gensub(/(^,|" *",)/,"","g",$0)}' inp
Product Name,City Location,Price Per Unit
banana,CA,5.7
apple,FL,2.3
$
```

Same code is more readable if split across a few lines :

```
$ awk -F, '
> NR<2{split(gensub(/Citty/,"City","g",$0),a,FS)}
> NR==2{for(b=2;b<=NF;b+=2){c=c a[b]" "$b","}print gensub(/,$/,"",1,c)}
> NR>2{print gensub(/(^,|" *",)/,"","g",$0)}' inp
Product Name,City Location,Price Per Unit
banana,CA,5.7
apple,FL,2.3
$
```

If 1st line, split the line into array elements within a.  Fix the Citty->City typo.

If 2nd line, starting with the 2nd column, print the corresponding column from 1st line together with this column.  Repeat for each column, going in 2 column increments.  Strip the trailing `,`.

After 2nd line, replace any leading `,` or any `"<spaces>",` with an empty string and then print the result.

*Tested ok on GNU Awk 4.0.2*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5Pa8MwDMXv@RRG5JBs6p95jB5aD0YhpxJKx05jA9v1illrG8ellCxffZ6Ttoehgx56ej@Jn75jrDcL2jZur0OxU6Y5imKy1CGcJwipnwFhB5hPS@RYvZZdvWGMtl/WF4LRuViwupqLe0bLVjJJ@Lv4AAK5SLHOeW0CuUExT0TAB5Q95Jm2/@3iE3@A3AGWw9r1aBcjrr3dHmVAIARweK2XSa@9lirDmh9UmgCurORBWzPYva88eTM6ZCi4SXWNLV8uqKfxLEPu3F7dAtXq4tDx4691PaqJowr/AA)

Comment: Great, thanks for that! However, I have 100+ columns in the csv. Is there a way to generalize that 3rd line for `NR>2` so that I don't need to specify 50 `$`? Also, the "Citty" typo could be on any odd-numbered column of the csv depending on how the file is formatted when I produce it. How would I generalize the typo replacement to check for a column match of "Citty" and then fix it for whatever column the typo was in? (Sorry I didn't mention it earlier; I've updated the question with this info)

Comment: Sure, now revised.

Answer (score 4):

Using Perl, with Text::CSV and MoreUtils:

```
perl -MText::CSV -MList::MoreUtils=pairwise -lne '
  BEGIN { $p = Text::CSV->new(); } 
  @f = $p->fields() if $p->parse($_);
  @hdr = map { s/Citty/City/ ; $_ } @f if $. == 1;
  @f = pairwise { $a . " " . $b } @hdr, @f if $. == 2;
  print join ",", grep { /\w/ } @f if $. > 1;
' file.csv
Product Name,City Location,Price Per Unit
banana,CA,5.7
apple,FL,2.3
```

The `grep` omits fields that do not contain at least one word character.

With perl >= 5.14.0 you can simplify the replacement to `map s/Citty/City/r @f` using the [Non-destructive substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions) modifier.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit nooby with bash scripting. How would I install those two modules/packages/libraries?

Comment: @takanuva15 what kind of Unix/Linux are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm running Windows and using a (Git) bash prompt to run/test the script on my local machine. I think the script will eventually go on our server, but I don't know the specific OS...I'll get back to you tomorrow on that.

Comment: @takanuva15 sorry I don't know anything about perl packaging in git bash

Comment: @takanuva15 If you're stuck testing on Windows, I would suggest installing WSL for a more complete environment that should be more or less portable to a real Linux distro. Git Bash has ... odd quirks.

Comment: @Bob Cool suggestion! I'm actually required to use company-approved software, so I don't have much flexibility in that regard.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
    awk -F, '
            {gsub (/,*"[    ]*",*/, ",")
             sub (/^,/, "")
             sub (/Citty/, "City")
            }

    NR == 1 {n = split ($0, T)
             next
            }
    NR == 2 {for (;n; n--) $n = T[n] " " $n
            }

    1
    ' OFS=, file
Product Name,City Location,Price Per Unit
banana,CA,5.7
apple,FL,2.3
```